# CakePHP Pagination: how can I sort by multiple columns to achieve "sticky" functionality?

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I see that this [paginate can't sort two columns at the same time](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1957) ticket is still open, which leads me to believe that what I'm trying to do is not possible without a workaround. So I guess what I'm looking for is a workaround.

I'm trying to do what many message boards do: have a "`sticky`" function. I'd like to make it so that no matter which table header link the user clicks on to sort, my model's "`sticky`" field is always the first thing sorted, followed by whatever column the user clicked on. I know that you can set `$this->paginate['Model']['order']` to whatever you want, so you could hack it to put the "`sticky`" field first and the user's chosen column second. The problem with this method is that pagination doesn't behave properly after you do it. The table header links don't work right and switching pages doesn't work right either. Is there some other workaround?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

User ten1 on the CakePHP IRC channel helped me find the solution. I told him that if he posted the answer here then I would mark it as the correct one, but he said I should do it myself since he doesn't have a Stack Overflow account yet.

The trick is to inject the "sticky" field into the query's "order" setting using the model's "beforeFind" callback method, like this:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    $sticky = array('Model.sticky' => 'DESC');

    if (is_array($queryData['order'][0])) {
        $queryData['order'][0] = $sticky + $queryData['order'][0];
    }
    else {
        $queryData['order'][0] = $sticky;
    }

    return $queryData;
}
```

Comment: a simple upvote didn't show how appreciative I am of this answer, so here's a comment really letting you know!

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom field for sorting and update pagination component.

**Controller code**

$order['Document.DATE'] = 'asc';

```
        $this->paginate = array(

                "conditions"=> $conditions ,
                "order" => $order ,
                "limit" => 10,
            **"sortcustom" => array('field' =>'Document.DATE' , 'direction' =>'desc'),**

            );
```

Changes in pagination component.

public function validateSort($object, $options, $whitelist = array()) {

```
    if (isset($options['sort'])) {
        $direction = null;
        if (isset($options['direction'])) {
            $direction = strtolower($options['direction']);
        }
        if ($direction != 'asc' && $direction != 'desc') {
            $direction = 'asc';
        }
        $options['order'] = array($options['sort'] => $direction);
    }

    if (!empty($whitelist) && isset($options['order']) && is_array($options['order'])) {
        $field = key($options['order']);
        if (!in_array($field, $whitelist)) {
            $options['order'] = null;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($options['order']) && is_array($options['order'])) {
        $order = array();
        foreach ($options['order'] as $key => $value) {
            $field = $key;
            $alias = $object->alias;
            if (strpos($key, '.') !== false) {
                list($alias, $field) = explode('.', $key);
            }

            if ($object->hasField($field)) {
                $order[$alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
            } elseif ($object->hasField($key, true)) {
                $order[$field] = $value;
            } elseif (isset($object->{$alias}) && $object->{$alias}->hasField($field, true)) {
                $order[$alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
            }
        }


        **if(count($options['sortcustom']) > 0 )
          {
            $order[$options['sortcustom']['field']] = $options['sortcustom']['direction']; 
          }**


        $options['order'] = $order;
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is code it in the action. Just create the query you want when some parameters exist on the URL. (parameters has to be sent by GET)

For example:

```
public function posts(){
    $optional= array();

    if(!empty($this->params->query['status'])){
                if(strlower($this->params->query['status']=='des')){
        $optional= array('Post.status DESC');
                }

                else if(strlower($this->params->query['status']=='asc')){
                    $optional= array('Post.status ASC');
                }
    }

    if(!empty($this->params->query['department'])){         
        //same...
    }

    //order first by the sticky field and then by the optional parameters.
    $order = array('Post.stickyField DESC') + $optional;


    $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'order' => $order,
            'paramType' => 'querystring',

    );

    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
}
```

I have used something similar to filter some data using `$conditions` instead of `$order` and it works well.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but the thing is I want the "sticky" field to be 100% transparent to the user. They should never be able to *not* have the sticky items be first. It shouldn't appear in the URL or anything, yet the sort links and page links should still work normally.

Comment: You can use your "sticky" field inside the code I posted and it will be totally transparent for the final user. The rest of the sorts, as it works with CakePHP sorts, are visible by URL, as always.

Comment: I have edited it to order it ALWAYS by the sticky field and optionally  by the URL params.

Comment: Shouldn't `=='des'` actually be `=='desc'`? Also, have you tested your code to verify that the sort links and the page links still function correctly?

Comment: Yeah. It should be **desc**. My mistake. And yes, it works well. As I told you, i have it working with optional $conditions. Don´t forget to use the 'paramType' => 'querystring', in the paginate array.

Answer (score 0):

Easy insert **'paramType' => 'querystring',** 
Show Code Example:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => array(
        'Post.name' => 'ASC',
        'Post.created' => 'DESC',

    ),
    'paramType' => 'querystring',

);

$this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
```